# How can this code be compacted further?

Tags: ruby

Can this line of code be made more compact?

```
db_tables_scanned = {}
IO.readlines(resume_log_file).each { |db_table| db_tables_scanned[db_table.split(".")[0].strip] << db_table.split(".")[1].strip if db_table.include? '.' } if resume and File.exists?(resume_log_file)
```

Comment: By using shorter variable names.

Comment: The variable names should be self-explanatory, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a one-liner? Here's a one-liner:

```
db_tables_scanned = resume and File.exists?(resume_log_file) ? Hash[IO.readlines(resume_log_file).map { |db_table| db_table.split(".").map(&:strip) if db_table.include? '.' }.compact] : {}
```

Of course this code is hideous. There is no need to get obsessed about getting less lines of code. Code has to:

1. Be human-readable
2. Use the most fitting and idiomatic abstractions of the language.

In this case, let's break it in lines, and use a `Hash[pairs_of_keys]` to build the hash:

```
db_tables_scanned = if resume and File.exists?(resume_log_file)
  Hash[IO.readlines(resume_log_file).map do |db_table|
    if db_table.include?('.')
      db_table.split(".").first(2).map(&:strip)
    end  
  end.compact]
else
  {}
end
```

Comment: Maintenance and readability are more important than saving carriage-returns and line-feeds any day. I would move the `db_tables_scanned` assignment into the `if` blocks also. Though we can assign outside an `if`, it is usually more readable to do it inside. Doing it outside is more "DRY" though.

Comment: @the Tin Man: Granted, there is no unanimity in the Ruby community whether if-blocks should be used as expressions or statements. I have a functional background, so obviously I feel very comfortable using it as an expression. I like specially how the scope of the code block is reduced, on a first glance I don't care what the block does, just that it returns a "db_tables_scanned" object. I just checked the official documentation and I was surprised to find an  example of this construction: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/ (section "Everything has a value")